# Expressão regular para obter a terceira parte de um parágrafo em HTML

Tags: regex

Criei essa regex e aparentemente está quase do jeito que gostaria, porém, eu gostaria de inserir a tag `<img>` após a terceira ocorrência de uma sequência de parágrafos. Da forma como eu fiz está inserindo o `<img>` após o primeiro paragrafo de todas as ocorrências.

Ou seja, a cada terceira ocorrência de um paragrafo `<p>`, eu gostaria de inserir uma tag `<img>`.

```
(<p(.*?)>)([[:space:]]+?|.*?|[[:space:]]+?)(<\/p>)
```

Aqui está o exemplo que fiz: https://regex101.com/r/8Dl1tr/1

Exemplo de como ficou minha regex:

Entrada de dados:

```
<p>texto1</p>
<p>texto1</p>
<p>texto1</p>
```

Resultado:

```
<p>texto1</p>
   <img src="">
<p>texto1</p>
   <img src="">
<p>texto1</p>
   <img src="">
```

**Aqui está como eu gostaria:**

```
<p>texto1</p>
<p>texto1</p>
<p>texto1</p>
   <img src="">

<p>texto1</p>
<p>texto1</p>
<p>texto1</p>
   <img src="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pegando de base o que você já havia feito, formulei esta regex:

```
((<p(.*?)>)([[:space:]]+?|.*?|[[:space:]]+?)(<\/p>)\s?){3}
```

As unicas mudanças que fiz foi adicionar tudo em um grupo unico e esperar que tenha 3 ocorrências(`{3}`).

> Veja funcionando no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8Dl1tr/2)